# PYTHON importing methods from class in module

Tags: python, class, methods, import, module

I am having a hard time using an attribute from a class in a module I made. I am using PyCharm and am trying to create a small game with pygame.

Here is the content of the module Player_class.py :

```
import pygame
# Créer une classe qui représente le joueur
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  

 def __init__(self):
 super().__init__()  # Permet d'utiliser le paramètre sprite de la super classe pygame.sprite.Sprite
 self.health = 100  # Points de vie variables durant le jeu
 self.max_health = 100
 self.attack = 10
 self.velocity = 5  # Vitesse du joueur en pixels
 self.image = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\Utilisateur\PycharmProjects\GravenJeu\assets\Jump (32x32).png")
 self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  # Pour avoir la position du joueur
 self.rect.x = 500
 self.rect.y = 600

 def move_right(self):
 self.rect.x += self.velocity

def move_left(self):
 self.rect.x -= self.velocity
```

---

Here is the code in the module Game_class.py:
from Player_class import Player

```
class Game:
 def __init__(self):
 self.player = Player()
 self.pressed = {}
```

---

And here is the code in main.py:

```
import pygame
from Game_class import Game
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Beach Brawl")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080,720))

# Import background
background = pygame.image.load("assets/beachBG.jpg")

# Charger le jeu
game = Game

# Charger le joueur
player = game.player()

# Boucle tant que cette condition est vraie
running = True
while running:

# Appliquer le background
 screen.blit(background,(-200,-50))

# Appliquer l'image du joueur
 screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)

# Mettre à jour l'écran
 pygame.display.flip()

#Si le joueur ferme cette fenêtre
 for event in pygame.event.get():
 # Pour vérifier que event = fermeture de fenetre
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
 pygame.quit()

# To detect if the player is pressing & releasing keys
 elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            game.pressed[event.key] = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            game.pressed[event.key] = False
```

---

The error I get from PyCharm is "Unresolved attribute reference 'pressed' for class 'Game'"
I know the trouble has to do with importing modules...
We can either import a full module and use it like this :

```
import Full_module

Full_module.function_in_module()
```

Or import the specific function from a module

```
from Full_module import function_in_module

function_in_module()
```

But since I am using classes and methods (I believe methods to be functions inside of classes), it might not be the same when it comes to importing and using them from a module.

My problem is with the self.pressed attribute in the Game class
"Unresolved attribute reference 'pressed' for class 'Game'"

Please help out a noob:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ...

```
game = Game
```

... but use ...

```
game = Game()
```

... instead.

A `game = Game` creates a variable `game` which receives the class (!!!) `Game`.

A `game = Game()` creates a variable `game` which will receive an instance of a class (!!!) of `Game`.

This should resolve your issue.

Remark: What you import from modules (typically) are functions and classes. While you invoke functions directly you (typically) dont's access members on classes directly. You can only do that if these members are static. However variables such as `pressed` aren't static, therefore you need to create an *instance* of your class `Game` first. (This is the very very very very typical way of how to structure programs. Static members are used only in very specific situations that don't apply here in your case.)

(So: This is not a matter of importing.)